Cannot persist null byte array
We're receiving following stacktrace when persisting a byte array as null using Spring Data:
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO "SOME_TABLE" 
("CONTENT") VALUES (?)]; SQL state [S0003]; error code [257]; Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1549)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:677)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1001)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:365)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:349)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.IdGeneratingInsertStrategy.execute(IdGeneratingInsertStrategy.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeInsertRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:85)
... 34 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:261)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1752)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:686)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:605)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7748)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4410)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:293)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:263)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:548)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$3(JdbcTemplate.java:1002)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)

We're receiving this using spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.3.1,
with version 3.2.0 everythings works.
Example implementation:
@Table("SOME_TABLE")
public record SomeTable(
    @Id @Column("ID")
    Long id,
    @Column("CONTENT")
    byte[] content
) {
}


public interface SomeTableRepository extends CrudRepository<SomeTable, Long> {
}


@DataJdbcTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@EnableJdbcRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    SomeTableRepository.class
})
@Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, value = {
    "classpath:0_init.sql",
    "classpath:1_load.sql"
})
@Sql(executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD, value = "classpath:2_clean.sql")
class ByteTest extends MssqlContainerBaseTest {

  @Autowired
  private SomeTableRepository someTableRepository;

  @Test
  void testByteArrayNotNull() {
      final SomeTable record = new SomeTable(null, "abc".getBytes());
      someTableRepository.save(record);
  }

  @Test
  void testByteArrayNull() {
      final SomeTable record = new SomeTable(null, null);
      someTableRepository.save(record);
  }

  @Test
  void testByteArrayEmpty() {
      final SomeTable record = new SomeTable(null, new byte[]{});
      someTableRepository.save(record);
  }

}

testByteArrayNull test method doesn't work. 
testByteArrayNotNull and testByteArrayEmpty test methods work fine. 
So we've a workaround by an using empty Byte array instead of null.
Although, null should be possible as it was by earlier versions.

Sounds like a bug, if you put the breakpoint onto NamedParameterJdbcTemplate do you see which parameter value it uses for null byte? vs what it uses for previous version

Probably need to activate verbose logging so you can see the raw T-SQL statement that it's submitting. At a guess it's trying to post 'null' instead of the bare keyword null.

I agree with @siggemannen, this sounds like a bug. A regression actually. Please file a ticket at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues Please make sure to include a reproducer, including the database either as in memory or using testcontainers.

@Jens Schauder, I filed a ticket like requested:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1827

This is related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25679 and can be resolved by setting
the system property - spring.jdbc.getParameterType.ignore=false
This can also be an entry in a spring.properties file in the root of the classpath.
See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1827#issuecomment-2211765960
